# Colour distortion of SVG object when moving and scaling in Inkscape

Tags: color, inkscape, svg

I downloaded an SVG file of button icons from Opengameart.org. I opened it in Inkscape. 
I selected and scaled all the button icons to let’s say 400%. 
Some are scaled fine but about half of them change their colour shade partially or the colour gets distorted, respectively.

This is the original object (exported to PNG).

[image: original]

And this is the distorted object after scaling:

[image: scaled]

How do I keep the original colour of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into *Edit > Preferences > Behaviour > Transform* settings. Make sure you have all the scale options checked: stroke widths, rounded corners, gradients, and patterns.  That should fix the problem.